# Doctrine Query Builder syntax error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a simply query in a repository like :

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ci');
    $qb->select('ci.id');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This query return me an error :

```
"An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT m0_.id AS id_0 FROM match m0_':\n\nSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match m0_' at line 1"
```

What's my problem ?

Comment: Please change `$qb->select('ci.id');`  to `$qb->select('id');` and check

Comment: is your table name 'match'? that is a reserved word in many (if not all) databases

Comment: My bad, it was the reserved word ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Match is a reserved keyword...and the name of my table !

Comment: please add how you fixed it, not only what the problem was